# Eclipse SQL Editor normal text color

Tags: sql, eclipse, editor, settings, textcolor

I was able to change all the other SQL syntax coloring in Eclipse Preferences, but the normal (non-Sql-syntactic) text is still black and I couldn't find where to find the setting for that. Black text is kind of hard to read against an almost black background. Thank you!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you are looking for the place to change the Text Editor color settings, go to Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors, select "Foreground color" in "Appearance color options", uncheck "System Default", click on the color and choose the color you want.

If you want to change the SQL Editor color settings, go to Preferences->Data Management->SQL Development->SQL Editor->Syntax Coloring.

Edit: You need to change the "Others" item in SQL Editor's syntax coloring. It's working on my Mac, anyway. First uncheck "Default foreground color" and then choose the color you want.

Edit: For those not seeing the change, after selecting "Apply and Close", you must Restart your workspace to see the changes.
   File -> Restart

Comment: That's a good, informative answer, BUT even after changing that, the text remains black. I'm using Eclipse Luna's built-in Dark Theme.

Comment: When I select that theme, both my SQL editor and my Text editor are still with black font on white background. Is that your problem? (I'm using a Mac)

Comment: Actually yes, with the exception that I've managed to change the background color to dark with some hassle, however the normal text color can't be changed with the same dark magic.

Comment: Then I don't get it. I was able to change it in the Preferences, like I said in my answer. Which editor are we actually talking about? The text editor or the sql editor? If it is the sql editor, what are you calling "normal text"?

Comment: For example in "CREATE TABLE Person" the word Person is black. Or home_address VARCHAR(255) the word home_address is black. Majority of the text is black. Syntax coloring affects SQL statements such as CREATE TABLE, CONSTRAINT etc.

Comment: So it's the SQL Editor. Normally, to change the elements you mentioned, you need to change the "Others" item in SQL Editor's syntax coloring. It's working on my Mac, anyway. First uncheck "Default foreground color" and then choose the color you want.

Comment: Yes, that's it! The settings are kind of confusing. You can edit that to your answer if you will. I'll check it as the correct answer.

Comment: The tip to restart finally did it for me

Answer (score 9):

[Alexis Dufrenoy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505714/alexis-dufrenoy) is absolutely right:

> If you want to change the SQL Editor color settings, go to Preferences->Sata Management->SQL Development->SQL Editor->Syntax Coloring.
>
> Edit: You need to change the "Others" item in SQL Editor's syntax coloring. It's working on my Mac, anyway. First uncheck "Default foreground color" and then choose the color you want.

Just in Luna release I have to **restart** Eclipse every time after changing SQL syntax coloring (other editors work without restart).

Its strange, but with Windows 7 its the only way.

Comment: Closing and re-opening the opened .sql files also work, without restarting the full program

Answer (score 6):

I was having trouble with the existing answers on Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)

Change the color of the "Others" option here to change the black text
[image]

You may also find it useful to similarly change the other options like "Single Quoted String" (blue default) , "Type" (purple default)

Answer (score 3):

Since 2019-03-14 there is standalone and very simple SQL editor plugin available at eclipse marketplace: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/sql-editor - it's just for editing SQL files, syntax highlighting and contains an experimental SQL formatter. It has full customizable colour preferences and also good looking defaults for dark theme -  see https://github.com/de-jcup/eclipse-sql-editor/wiki

It is open source, works out of the box, is small and has no dependencies.
So it could be a good alternative.

**PS: I am the author of the mentioned plugin.**

Comment: @MartijnPieters : I added the disclosure. I do not want to make commercials here, but I had the same questions before I started to write my plugin... So I thought it is okay.

Comment: Sure, within reason. But a recommendation to use a plugin from someone else has *different weight* from the same message coming from the author of the code. You are naturally biased, after all.

Comment: without beeing able to (mark and) execute the code it's not really a good alternative for me.

Comment: @AndreasCovidiot: If you need to execute the SQL statements from the IDE you should use DBeaver instead.

Comment: @de-jcup thx - perfect, much more feature-rich than the standard *Database Tools* and an extensive tool also providing nice coloring

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain this issue from the problem to the answer:

First, the problem is illegible statements etc in the sql editor(fig 342) -
[image]

My solution is:

First, install DBeaver from the Eclipse Marketplace(fig 343) -
[image]

Second, change colors in Window > Preferences > (follow steps 1 ~ 6 : fig 344) -
[image]

Third, click Apply on the Pref' window(fig 345) -
[image]

As the result, you'll get legible text below(fig 347) -
[image]

The End.